# C# EXT : call javascript code from code behind

Tags: c#, extjs, ext.net

I am trying to call javascript code in code behind (.aspx.cs) to reload a page like this:

```
X.Js.AddScript("parent.EBodyPanel.activeTab.reload();");
```

But its not working (no js error) , I tried with simpler alert function:

```
X.Js.AddScript("alert('reload');");
```

But still no luck. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you'll need to post a simplified sample that demonstrates the scenario. Hard to say what's going wrong here. The code you provided looks correct.